# Save csv as attachment file a PHP+Apache setup not working

Tags: php, csv, save, content-disposition

I have a interesting problem that I think is server related.  I want CSV data to be saved as a CSV file when a user clicks a button.  It works fine on my development server, but on the production it just echo's the content to the page.  My guess is that it must be a server issue, but I'm really not sure what it could be.  Can GZIP affect this?

My header code is as follows:

```
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
echo $out;
```

So this code above works on a development server and on the production will just echo the CSV to the page.  Any ideas?

Comment: Referring to Christian's response, I examined the HTTP and the live server is not the same.  It adds this:

Vary: Accept-Encoding

And then the Content-Type is not what I specify in php and resorts to:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: You could add more details about the configuration of the live server now, maybe we can find the configuration setting that caues it

Comment: Looking at the W3C docs for HTTP/1.1 the Vary keyword will change the content-type if the content-type that you defined is not on the list. So you would need to add it to the list in httpd.conf or .htaccess. Possibly adding text/x-csv to the Accept-Encoding header would do the trick.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html (scroll down to 14.44)
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can think of is the mime-type. I've had some problems with mime-types (especially with .flv files) when moving from one server to another.

What I've used for .csv files is `application/octet-stream`.

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried application/octet-stream with the same problem... thanks though

Comment: added application/octet-stream csv to my /etc/mime.types file and reloaded httpd service and it began working correctly:  CentOS 5.0 production server.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I'd guess it's the mime-type as well. You may want to try the csv specific "text/csv" ([RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-3)) or the generic "application/octet-stream".

Answer (score 0):

Just use Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org) and capture the HTTP-traffic for both cases and look for differences. Fiddler is also supposed to work

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried out fiddler and interestingly enough the header on the live server is set to:

text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

and not

text/x-csv

I'm not sure why it would be overriden though... really strange.